# Adding Xcode Workspace Schemes to Version Control

Tags: xcode, version-control

I'd like to share Workspace Schemes that I've created with the other team members. However they are all stored under  .xcodeproj > xcuserdata > .xcuserdatad > xcschemes. I've set xcuserdata folders to be ignore in SVN as I assumed all data in that folder were user specific.

Is there a way around this? i.e I don't want the schemes to be user specific. Or should I check the xcschemes folder in anyway. And if I do that will the other users be able to see and use my schemes?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Choose Manage Schemes from the Schemes control. Check "Shared" beside any schemes you'd like to share. The schemes will be moved into a folder called "xcshareddata".

**Update:** This works the same for Xcode 4-8.

Comment: I can't see why the default is **not** shared. That makes me wonder what I am missing… Is this just an odd default, or is there a good reason why a scheme would generally not be shared?

Comment: This works, but unfortunately it embeds an absolute path in the .xcscheme file if the Executable is set to anything but "None". Hand editing the path in XML to a relative path causes a crash in XCode. So even though it's "Shared", it contains user specific data.

Comment: @bluebadge I'm not seeing the behavior you mention in the Xcode 7.0 GM. I just followed my own directions and the .xcscheme file contains no paths; just "container:MyProjectName.xcodeproj". Are you using Xcode 7? Are you using a Workspace? What "Container" is selected for the scheme in the Manage Schemes sheet? More info is needed.

Comment: Worked for me in XCode 9

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to go into the "Manage Schemes" view and check off the 'Shared' checkbox ('Product' menu -> Scheme -> Manage Schemes...).

Next, You'll need to remove 'xcshareddata/xcschemes' from your ignore file and add them to the repo (or just use 'git add -f MyProject.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes')