# GCDAsyncSocket restart readDataToData memory increasing

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, memory, gcdasyncsocket

I have a class that connects via `GCDAsyncSocket` to a home automation host and reads the events continuously. In some big configurations there could be a few events per second sometimes just a few events per minute. That works so far.

Now I recognized in Xcode that my Memory is growing bigger an bigger. After a few minutes running memory went up to 60-70MB and growing. So there must be something wrong.

I found the problem in my `didReadData` method (last 3 lines) when i'm restarting the `readDataToData`

```
func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket!, didReadData data:NSData, withTag tag:Int) {

    guard let rsp = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) where rsp != "" else {
        print("error - respone is empty")
        return
    }

    // \n entfernen
    let response = rsp.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

    printVerbose("FHEM: didReadDataWithTag \(tag) and response \(response)", withVerbose: 6)

    // Got Data from Events
    if( tag == self.tags.getEvents ){

        printVerbose("FHEM: didReadDataWithTag \(tag) and response \(response)", withVerbose: 5)

        if( self.event == nil ) {
            self.event = FHEMEvent()
            print("neue instanz")
        }

        self.event!.update(response)

        guard let devices = self.devices where devices.count > 0 else {
            print("No Devices found")
            return
        }

        for device in devices {

            if( device.name == self.event!.name ) {

                for reading in device.readings {

                    if( reading.0 == self.event!.reading ) {
                        print("FHEM: Reading Update erkannt. \(self.event!.name) -> \(self.event!.reading) -> \(self.event!.value)")

                        // MARK: Check ob Delegate Methode implementiert wurde
                        if( self.delegate?.didGetFHEMReadingsUpdate != nil ) {
                            self.delegate?.didGetFHEMReadingsUpdate!(self.event!.name, reading: self.event!.reading, value: self.event!.value)
                        }
                        else {
                            print("No method implemented")
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        self.event = nil

        // Read again - HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        let seperatorString = "\n"
        let seperatorData = seperatorString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        socket.readDataToData(seperatorData, withTimeout: -1, tag: self.tags.getEvents)

    }

}
```

When i'm commenting these lines the read operation will not start again, but my memory problem is also away ;)

My events struct:

```
struct FHEMEvent {

    var timestamp:String = ""
    var time:String = ""
    var type:String = ""
    var name:String = ""
    var reading:String = ""
    var value:String = ""

    mutating func update( response:String ) {

        let array = response.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

        if( array.count < 5 ) {
            return
        }

        let timestamp = array[0]
        let time = array[1]
        let type = array[2]
        let name = array[3]
        var reading = array[4]

        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.time = time
        self.type = type
        self.name = name

        // reading ist wirklich ein Reading
        if( reading.regExp("^.*:$") == true ) {

            reading.removeAtIndex(reading.endIndex.predecessor())

            var value:String = ""

            if( array[5] != "" ) {
                value = array[5]
            }
            else {
                return
            }

            self.reading = reading
            self.value = value
        }

        // reading ist STATE
        else {
            self.reading = "state"
            self.value = reading
        }   
    }
}
```

Has anybody a suggestion?

Greets from Austria!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Xcode instruments for the memory leak? My guess is your seperatorData / String didn't get deallocated (or at least not fast enough).

I had an similar issue with GCDAsyncSocket and a manual "autorelease pool" solved it, but first you should be sure it's a memory leak.

Comment: Yes i tried this before and now again. After 35 min Xcode says "Finished running ...". I dont know what is happen i was'nt in the room. No leaks were detected after 35min running. The app memory increased from about 7mb to 240mb.

Comment: Ok, Xcode says "Finished running" when i'm starting instruments. Sorry, i'm quite new to xcode.  I tried it with another home automation installation, with less events. Same result, just slower.

Comment: Okay, but then you should be able to see which objects we're created during this memory increase. Take a look at the persistent memory area. You should use the "Mark Generation" button, then you could easily compare and see which objects are problematic.

Comment: Ok, i think i have to get a tutorial for instruments on youtube first. I dont really unterstand what this tool shows me. I made two screenshot. I hope it helps. http://up.picr.de/23575928tl.jpg http://up.picr.de/23575929ep.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in GCDAsyncSocket. I found a solution to my problem in [Adding Xcode Workspace Schemes to Version Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144316/adding-xcode-workspace-schemes-to-version-control).

DLDR; Disabled Queue Debugging (Edit Scheme > Run/Debug > Options)